# Program exits immediately when entering an out of range number for char

Tags: c, integer, char, exit

I have a program written in C.  The following is a snippet of the program:

```
signed char answer;

printf("----Technology Quiz----\n\n");
printf("The IPad came out in which year?\n");
printf("Year: ");
scanf("%c", &answer);
printf("\n\n");
printf("The answer you provided was: %c\n\n", answer);
```

This is not the whole program.  After this code, there is a check which verifies whether the user guessed the year or not.

As you can see, the user can never guess the answer since a signed char only accept input from -128 to 127.  This is intentional.

The problem with this program is that if the user enters a number outside a character's range, the program just exits immediately.  The program behaves as if there are no getchar() s at the end, even though there is.  How can I solve this problem please?

**Edit**

If the input is out of range, the program behaves like an application where the user forgot to include getchar() at the end.

Comment: `an application where the user forgot to include getchar() at the end`. What does it mean?

Comment: It means that when the application runs, it does not wait for the user to press enter.  Therefore, the user does not see the result on the screen as the program is executed too fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scanf("%c", &answer);
```

takes only one character from the input stream, so if the user enters the year as e.g. 1952, there remain 4 characters in the input stream after the '1' has been assigned to `answer` (952 and the '\n').

So unless you have enough `getchar()`s at the end, there is enough remaining input to satisfy them immediately.

If you want input of the form 123 converted to a `signed char`, you should use the `%hhd` format,

```
scanf("%hhd", &answer);
```

but `scanf` doesn't check for overflow, so entering out-of-range values results in undefined behaviour (overflow of signed integers). To get overflow control, you should read a line (or a part of one) into a buffer,

```
char buf[30];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
```

and parse the input manually. Unfortunately, there is no standard conversion `strtoxy` for `signed char`, so you should use `strtol` to convert the input to a `long`, and then check for out-of-range values.

Comment: If I input 100, the program works fine.  However, if I provide a number greater than 128, the program works as described above.  Edit: I made a mistake.  The program behaves as you described.

Comment: How many `getchar()`s have you? And show more of the code, from the given, we can only see that the `scanf` uses just one character of the input. Does it behave differently when you enter 128 vs. 127?

Comment: You are right.  Sorry my mistake.  If I enter 127, the program works uncorrectly.  I just want to capture my input in a signed 8-bit integer.  I tried using _int8 but I don't know what format specifier to use with scanf.

Comment: For a signed 8-bit integer, using `signed char` is usually fine, the format to have it convert 123 would be `%hhd`, two 'h' to tell it the size, a 'd' for decimal numbers. But I don't think `scanf` does overflow detection, so when an out-of-range value is entered, you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: I tried using hhd but Visual Studio keeps telling me that the stack variable around 'answer' is corrupted.

Comment: Visual Studio? Hmm, not sure if the `hh` length modifier is C99 (which Microsofts C compiler doesn't support) or was already in C89. Anyway, the way using `fgets` ought to also work with C89.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)  I did what you told me and now everything is working fine :)